# Is there a difference between Java Float/Double and VB.NET's Float/Double

Tags: java, .net, floating-point

Is there a difference between Java Float/Double Type and VB.NET's Float/Double Type?

edit: are they both use the same specification? (IEEE 754)

Comment: The answer is either "yes" or "no", depending on the kind of differences you are asking about.  Please be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

[VB-Double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99xtshc.aspx)

> Holds signed IEEE 64-bit (8-byte) double-precision floating-point
>   numbers that range in value from -1.79769313486231570E+308 through
>   -4.94065645841246544E-324 for negative values and from 4.94065645841246544E-324 through 1.79769313486231570E+308 for positive values. Double-precision numbers store an approximation of a real
>   number.

[Java-Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

> The double data type is a double-precision 64-bit IEEE 754 floating
>   point. Its range of values is beyond the scope of this discussion, but
>   is specified in the Floating-Point Types, Formats, and Values section
>   of the Java Language Specification. For decimal values, this data type
>   is generally the default choice.

Answer (score 2):

In Java a float is a 32 bit IEEE 754 floating point and a double is a 64 bit IEEE 754 floating point. This is a standard and irrespective of the machine.

I am not aware of any similar standard that applies to VB.NET. This is a good reference point:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7(v=vs.80).aspx

So, at present they are the same *size*, but I don't think you can guarantee for ever. They may or may not have the same allocation of bits between mantissa and exponent though.

(Remember that an Integer in VBA, for example, is still 16 bits!)